# Making custom events on webworkers

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I made a webworker and tried to add a custom event called progress as follows:

```
self.updateProgress = function(no){
    let event = new CustomEvent(
        'progress',
        {
            detail : {
                description: "event from webworker to update progress",
                timeofevent: new Date(),
                eventcode: 15
            },
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: false,
            data : no
        });
        self.console.log(self.dispatchEvent(event));
    };
```

On the parent JavaScript:

```
scope.worker.addEventListener('progress', (e) => { //cannot add custom events to worker yet
    scope.progress = e.data;
});
```

The problem is that the event is never triggered, and from what I have read, it seems that message and error are the only events that are attached to the worker object. Is it impossible to add custom events?

Comment: Something wrong with your code block, please edit your question and correct it.

Comment: Fixed it.. please let me know if I am doing it wrong. the original code was clean.

Comment: It's fine now, I also added the JavaScript tag so that you get syntax highlighting as well.

Comment: thanks.. still figuring this out

Answer (score 3):

You set `worker.addEventListener('message', (e) => {})` in main thread, but you don't `self.dispatchEvent` at worker. Instead, you call `self.postMessage(obj, []);` and worker implementation does the job (passing data between threads and firing events).

Proto of `WebWorker` is `EventTarget` in Chrome, so you probably could use it as event target where you create it. But `worker` in main thread and `self` in worker are not the same object / scope, so you dispatch event and listen event on different targets.

But nothing prevents you from using standard `self.postMessage` way for keeping track of loading progress.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. however, I wanted to see if I could add my own custom event to communicate between the worker thread and the UI thread.. postMessage triggers a message event handler in the UI thread but I wanted to have a separate event handler triggered from the worker thread without having to go through the postMessage route. As far as I could find out... the event handlers on the worker are fixed.